# how to restart the execution of a test case in selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a test case which stops and throws an error "Element not found".

Now what I want to do is, I want to selenium ide to refresh the page and run the script from beginning.

All I want to know is that, is there any way to make this happen in Selenium IDE. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. First of all, you should have a `try-except-else` structure. Then you should have a `while True` loop and specify the `NoSuchElementException` for continuing from the beginning of the loop. In the first line of this `except` block, you put a line as `driver.refresh()`. In the `else` block you `break` the loop and consider that you should have two `except` block; one for `NoSuchElementException` and another for other exceptions. In the second you should `break` the loop I guess. Here's a sample code:

```
import selenium.common.exceptions as SeleniumExceptions
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_id('some_id')
        # do whatever you want

    except SeleniumExceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        driver.refresh()
        continue

    except:
        print sys.exc_info()
        break

    else:
        break
```

**EDIT1:**

Consider that if you have to work with a specific `frame` or `iframe`, you should switch back to it with `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id('frame_id'))` and continue your work; or if you think you should wait for the frame to load, you can use this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_id('frame_id')))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot zeinab for your valuable response. I'll try that right away!

Comment: zeinab I guess this might be the webdriver code, isn't it?
I want to do this in SELENIUM IDE, can u help?

Comment: I didn't work much with SELENIUM IDE, but maybe I can try to find a way. I'll let you know if I do.

Comment: that would be great, and I am really thankful to you, for when i implement this using webdriver, this will be really helpful. Arigato! :)